# Hovering on link does not execute javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an image appear when I hover over a link, but I cannot get the `.hover()` event to work. To start, I am just trying to get an alert to appear. Once I can do that, I know how to fade things in and out, but in the meantime, I would just like the `jQuery` to work.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="timeslot" id="d1_0">
    <ul class="_ts">
        <li><a class="new_appt" href="#">Open</a><a class="delete_appt" href="#"><img src="<?php echo  plugins_url('/scheduler/img/untick.png');?>"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript/jQuery I'm using:

```
    $('.new_appt').hover(function(){
             //mouse over
         $(this).alert("test");
            //mouse exit
         $(this).alert("complete"); 
});
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: That's not how you bind a pair of mouseover/mouseout handlers with jQuery. Read the API documentation carefully: http://api.jquery.com/hover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are intending on using it, `hover()` needs two handlers, one for `handlerIn` and one for `handlerOut`. It should be:

```
$('.new_appt').hover (
    function(){
        //mouse over
        $(this).alert("test");
    }, 
    function() {
        //mouse exit
        $(this).alert("complete"); 
    }
);
```

Comment: There is an extra `}` in there. And it didn't seem to work :/

Comment: I'm sorry, it did work. Thank you! (But there is an extra `}` in there) :)

Comment: Yep, there was an extra `}`... Fixed now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Steve has replied your question. Hover is simply a short hand of:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

i.e

```
$( selector ).mouseenter(function(){
    //mouse over
    $(this).alert("test");
} ).mouseleave( function() {
    //mouse exit
    $(this).alert("complete"); 
} );
```